# How to fix my text rotator so that it cycles through a list of words?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a text rotator which show a different text when someone refresh the page.

This is what I have created:

HTML below:

```
<div id="t1"></div>
```

JavaScript below:

```
var scn = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

$(function() {
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length),
  rand2 = rand1 === scn.length-1 ? 0 : rand1 + 1;
  $('#t1').html(scn[rand1]);    
});
```

It's working fine but choosing random and most of the time the first value it chooses I am trying to make it like go from red, blue, green, yellow, and after yellow, then it goes to red and continue the circle again and again.

Comment: Why are you using random if you don't want it random?  Use a counter instead.

Comment: okay i will try to learn jscript more i thought they will go from 0 to 1 2 3 but this dont happen:)

Comment: @halfer Then a comment to that effect, a down vote or a close vote (or all of the above) are warranted. But, an incorrect edit is always an incorrect edit.

Comment: John, for future questions, please make your titles more specific if you can. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Thanks!

Comment: sure but my partner was warned not to use how to in the tittle coz it looks more like a request not like a question

Comment: @john: a title style of "How to ..." or "How can I ..." is fine, as it indicates you know you will be doing the work. "Please help me to..." is a euphemism for "Please do this for me", and is best avoided. In my view, your partner is incorrect - do please let them know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rand2` variable (that does the work of making sure you circle back around to the beginning of the array) is never getting used.

You can store the counter (that represents which array item to extract) in the user's **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** so that it is not lost between page visits.

Here's an example but note that it won't actually work, here in the Stack Overflow code snippet environment, due to security constraints, but you can see it work **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ct8mc4u0/1/)** (Just keep hitting the "Run" button on that page).

```js
var scn = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

$(function() {
  // Attempt to get the counter out of storage and covert back to a number
  var counter = +localStorage.getItem("counter");

  // If the user has NOT been here before create new counter
  if(!counter){
    // Initialize to a random
    counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length);  
  }
  
  // If the counter has reached the end of the array items, reset to 0
  counter = counter >= scn.length ? 0 : counter;
  $('#t1').text(scn[counter++]);  // show the item from the array and advance the counter
  
  // Store the counter in the user's localStorage for their next page load
  localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For rotator function on page load you cannot rely on Math.random as it gives any random number. You need to use counter, and most importantly save it some storage, otherwise on next page load your counter will set to it's default value all the time. Here's the code:

```
var scn = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

$(function() {
  var currentIndex = +localStorage.getItem('index');
  if (isNaN(currentIndex) || (currentIndex === scn.length)) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  $('#t1').html(scn[currentIndex]);
  localStorage.setItem('index', ++currentIndex);
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/6yakth0q/2/

Comment: You can rely on a random number if it is constrained to a number that is within the array's index boundaries, which is exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: The question is kind of indeterminate, but although `Math.random()` is used in the code example, the question states to _show a **different** text when someone refresh the page_. Both interpretations look equally valid to me.

Comment: @Scott but how do you make sure that the numbers always come in cyclic order, as in 1,2,3,4,1,2,...

Comment: @SachinSingh Have you looked at my answer? The random is only used once (when the user first visits the page), then it is stored in `localStorage`. From then on that number is just used as the starting number **and is increased after use and re-stored**. This way, you always advance to the next number (or start back at 0 if you've reached the end).

Comment: @SachinSingh Just to be clear, the OP doesn't need the first number you ever obtain to be `0`, that's where the random comes in. Initially, get any random that falls within the array bounds. From that point forward, increment it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am a little confused with what you are trying to imply. And how is my solution different from yours except that I am not using Math.random(). What I meant with my answer was Math.random always produces a random number hence using it will not produce a cyclic order if called on page load. You just fixed it by using localStorage as you prevented the use Math.random on subsequent load. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @SachinSingh I am just answering the question(s) you've asked me. I am confused at what you are confused about. Yes, my answer uses a random (as the OP asks for) and yes, my answer ensures that it only gets a random once and from then on the numbers are cyclical. What's the problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am confused because your original answer has changed :)
I believe I saw an answer where you were trying to produce cyclic results on button click. And I did not see the use Math.random. Now do you get what I am confused about? I am sorry I might not have noticed the change in your answer. Or perhaps it was someone else who posted that. And I answered to the first comment you posted.
The code snippet john has attached has Math.random function called on every page load.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was willing to give a thumbs up to your answer but I don't know why we are having this conversation. I have changed my mind. You can give a thumbs down to mine if you want.

Comment: Yes, my first answer used a button to advance the counter. I didn't notice the requirement to have the counter stored right away. When I did, I updated my answer. But again, what's the problem?

Comment: We're having this conversation because you keep asking me questions and I'm answering them?!